# Python calculation incredibly slow Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: python, cpu, 20.10

My laptop is an MSI with a hexcore i7-9750H CPU, NVIDIA RTX2060 6GB GPU, a 1TB SSD, and 64GB of RAM. Since "upgrading" from 18.04 to 20.10 the performance is abysmal. I work most in Python and calculations that used to take 5-10 seconds are now taking 50-60 seconds. For example, running a basic parameter optimization of a lasso regression in python takes like 45 seconds for a tiny (2000 row) dataset.  The slowdown is STAGGERING. Am I missing something fundamental here?  I've never experienced anything like this in 20 years of linux use.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you provide a usable test case so we can compare? It's very difficult to answer the question with so little detail.

Comment: If your application is single threaded, try forcing CPU affinity. If you are using the powersave CPU frequency scaling governor (which would be the default) try the performance governor. (Do: `echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`). Otherwise, and like @popey said, give us a simple example to try.

Comment: @DougSmythies: thanks, it's set to performance. 
@popey: sorry for lack of specificity. I'm calculating a loss function for an elasticnet regression and it's taking forever. But I tried this as a (probably poor) speed proxy:
`import numpy as np`
`a = np.random.random((10000,10000))`
`%timeit np.dot(a,a)`
That's giving me 11 seconds vs 17 seconds on my older 4-core machine w/ 16gb ram. Roughly, the new machine used to run at about 40% of the time of the old machine, rather than 65% of the time.

Comment: interesting... your example takes 9 minutes and 26 seconds on my i5-9600K, and it is pinned at 4.6 GHz during execution. Ubuntu 20.04 server. Note: could not get %timeit or timeit to work, so that is the time for everything, including random numbers generation. i.e I did `time ./simple-math-test.py`

Comment: I would be very grateful for an update on your issue. And do you know why we differ so dramatically on the overall times?

Answer (score 0):

This is less of an answer and more of a comparison.

My test results, using the example code, and done on VMs.
Host: Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid ; i7-2600K
VM1: Ubuntu desktop, 20.10, python 3.8.6
VM2: Ubuntu desktop, 18.04.5 LTS, python 2.7.17 and python 3.6.9

VM1: 13 minutes and 39 seconds
VM2: 12 minutes and 43 seconds (python 3.6.9)
VM2: 12 minutes and 37 seconds (python 2.7.17)

7% degradation for 20.10 verses 18.04.

Concurrently, I always have turbostat running, on the host in this example, watching for any signs of throttling, either by power limits or temperature limits for whatever. (actually, I know that there won't be for this test, but due diligence.)(Note: RAMWatt is actually not available on this processor.):

```
doug@s15:~/iso$ sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt --interval 30
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt
12.66   3795    15374   58      27.97 <<< 8 CPUs, 1 at 100%
12.70   3794    14718   58      28.01 <<< not too hot
12.68   3794    16987   59      28.01 <<< not too much power, TDP=95
12.67   3796    12782   60      28.01 <<< CPU frequency pinned
12.67   3795    16558   59      28.03
12.68   3795    14234   59      28.02
12.67   3794    16392   59      28.00
12.69   3794    14459   58      27.99
12.67   3795    15074   59      28.02
12.69   3795    14088   59      28.02
12.69   3794    17271   59      28.03
12.73   3793    16606   59      28.04
12.68   3794    16550   59      27.96
12.70   3794    14759   58      27.96
12.70   3793    18363   60      27.98
12.72   3793    17089   59      28.01
12.70   3794    17496   60      28.00
12.72   3793    17314   59      28.01
11.11   3792    15402   48      25.00  <<< done
0.22    2474    7189    40      4.33
0.30    2725    10450   41      4.42
0.26    2764    6473    35      4.26
```

Note the slight CPU frequency variation is due to multi active cores, as per this (from running turbostat without the --quiet command line option):

```
cpu4: MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT: 0x23242526
35 * 100.0 = 3500.0 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
36 * 100.0 = 3600.0 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
37 * 100.0 = 3700.0 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
38 * 100.0 = 3800.0 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
```