# FPS in games has dropped dramatically in the past few weeks

Tags: nvidia, graphics, games, steam

This past winter I was able to play games like Dark Souls 3 at around 55~60 fps consistently throughout the whole game. I didn't play any graphics intensive games for a while and booted the game back up and got 7 FPS! I tested other games that I was able to play successfully at high frame rates and they have all dropped to ridiculously low fps. I tried installing a new Steam proton version, like golden eggroll but it didn't affect anything. I tried using a benchmark test like glmark2, where I got 361, which seems very low for my system.

System specs:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.10
- Memory: 8gb
- CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz × 12
- GPU: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]

To the best of my ability to tell I am using updated graphics drivers for NVIDIA. I don't notice any problems outside of gaming. In fact, most low specs games (such as Psychonauts) run very stable. It is just extra confusing because my system seemed to be running fine a few weeks ago, and without changing anything noticeable things stopped working.

Any ideas?

Comment: this is the 2nd or 3rd question involving slow downs and i7-9750H in the last couple of days. Interesting. Look for some throttling, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319880/python-calculation-incredibly-slow-ubuntu-20-10). If it is graphics related, I can not help, as I am a server person.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by buying a new laptop charger. My old one was faulty and wasn't working properly. Not sure exactly why this was happening due to that but it is fixed now.